# Reading a text file with boolean values into an array list as objects

Tags: java, arraylist, interface, boolean

I am trying to read a file of string int and boolean values into an array list as object blocks. The string values go into the array list just fine, its the boolean values I'm having trouble with. Every time I encounter the variable 'active'there is a mismatch exception. Please help! The text file for if the block is a wizard goes in this order
name (string)
location (string)
active (boolean) ... the one I'm having issues with
skill level (int)
friendliness (int)

I included the driver class as well as the Witch class which contains the 
variable 'active' originally.

[image]

```
Driver class that adds objects to the array list based on what the scanner 
reads from the file
    package project2;

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Project2 {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner inputFileScanner1 = null;

        //file name
        String listFile = "list.txt";

        // Check to see if file exists
        try {
          inputFileScanner1 = new Scanner(new File(listFile));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

          System.out.println("Error opening file.");
          System.exit(1);
        }

        //create Individuals arraylist and Location arraylist
        ArrayList < Individual > Individual = new ArrayList < > ();
        ArrayList < String > Location = new ArrayList < > ();

        //declare variables to read file contents into the arraylist
        String wizName, witchName, individualName, location, position, 

        profession = null, line = null;
        int wizLevel, witchSkillLevel, friendliness;
        boolean active;

        //while there is a next line, if the line equals Wizard, the next                                        four lines
        // are wizard name, location, position and level
        while (inputFileScanner1.hasNext()) {
          line = inputFileScanner1.nextLine();
          if (line.trim().equals("Wizard")) {

            wizName = inputFileScanner1.nextLine().trim();
            location = inputFileScanner1.nextLine().trim();
            position = inputFileScanner1.nextLine().trim();
            wizLevel = inputFileScanner1.nextInt();

            //create wizard object
            Individual wizard = new Wizard(wizName, location, position, profession, wizLevel);

            //fill arraylist with wizard objects
            Individual.add(wizard);
            Location.add(location);

          } //if the next line is Witch, the next five lines are
          // witch name, location, yes/no active, skill level, and friendliness
          //in that order
          else if (line.trim().equals("Witch")) {
            witchName = inputFileScanner1.nextLine().trim();
            location = inputFileScanner1.nextLine().trim();
            active = inputFileScanner1.nextBoolean();
            witchSkillLevel = inputFileScanner1.nextInt();
            friendliness = inputFileScanner1.nextInt();

            //create witch object
            Individual witch = new Witch(witchName, location, profession, witchSkillLevel, friendliness, active);

            //fill the arraylist with witch objects
            Individual.add(witch);
            Location.add(location);
          } else {

            profession = line.trim();
            individualName = inputFileScanner1.nextLine().trim();
            location = inputFileScanner1.nextLine().trim();

            Individual i = new Individual(profession, individualName, location);

            Individual.add(i);
            Location.add(location);
          }
          java.util.Collections.sort(Individual);
          java.util.Collections.sort(Location);

        }

        System.out.println("List of friends and possible allies: " + Location);

        inputFileScanner1.close();

      }

    }
```

//Witch class which holds values that are in the text file. active is the boolean value Im having trouble with
    package project2;

```
 public class Witch extends Individual implements Magical {

      private int skill;
      private int friendly;

          //Constructor with witch parameters
      public Witch(String name, String location, String profession,
        int skill, int friendly, boolean active) {

      }

      //default constructor
      public Witch() {

      this("", "", "", 0, 0, false);
      }

      //overridden abstract method from magical interface 
      @Override
      public void assess() {
        System.out.print(this.friendly + " " + this.skill + " " + super.toString());
      }
    }

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Text file :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6MBZ.png)

Comment: Could you add a portion of the file that the system is reading?

Comment: I added an image of the contents of the file. The format is Wizard (keyword), full name, location, position, level ... Witch(keyword), full name, location, active (boolean), skill level, friendliness ... any other profession, full name, location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pull in your boolean variable do something like this.

```
if(inputFileScanner1.nextLine().trim().equals("yes"))
{
    active = true;
}
else
{
    active = false;
}
```

Comment: If the answer is correct click the check mark under the down symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is that the file contains the strings `yes` and `no`, that are not directly parsable as booleans (should be `true` or `false`).

If you can change the original data file somehow, I would suggest to use the two `true` and `false` keywords, otherwise, the @Sendrick Jefferson solution will do the job (at your own risk: every typo, as for instance "ye", will be translated into false).

Comment: Yeah we aren't allowed to change the file :( But thank you so much for the help!